# Не отслеживается нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, phonegap

Доброго всем времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
      alert('Hello!');
      document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, true);
}

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    alert('menu key down');
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку меню ничего не происходит. Аналогичным образом пытался отловить событие для searchbutton и т.п. Пример брал отсюда   http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton

Comment: Вы обернули document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); в onLoad и добавили onLoad в body onload, как в вашем примере?

Comment: LinnTroll, спасибо большое за ответ. Я нашел проблему. Дело в том, что я делал очень простую обертку вокруг сайта, сверстанного под мобилку. Соответственно, приложение редиректит на страницу сайта
    window.location="http://site.ru/mobile";

и это служит проблемой. Если же я закомментировал эту строку, то приложение начинает отслеживать нажатие. Пока не знаю, как решить эту проблему, т.к. в первую очередь нужна лишь очень простая обертка с несколькими фичами, вроде уведомления и телефонного меню.